# Handling the deletion of old database objects

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a few core data entities in my app.

One entity for example, is a more complicated one and represents a task. Something like 12 fields consisted of the premetive types of String and Int and some relationship to "premetive" core data entities, like an entity that represents an hour in the day and consists of two fields of int.

Are this type of objects can actually effect the device free space in any significant way in the long term of months and years ? Should I routinly delete them ?

Answer (score 0):

All data that your app saves affects the free space on the device. Whether it's significant depends on how much data you're saving. If it's 1 or 2 old instances and the strings are short, nobody will ever notice. If it's 1 or 2 billion old instances or if some strings can be really long, you need to take some action.

In general you should delete any data you won't use any more. Not "routinely", but literally as soon as you're sure you don't need it any more. Not deleting it is sloppy programming that shows lack of care for your users. Nobody expects you to be perfect, of course, but if you don't need the data, you should delete it. And of course, it's OK to cache some data that you don't need right now but that you might download from a web API in the near future.

If you do need the data though, don't delete it. If there's a lot of it, look in to whether some can be moved off of the device to a web service of some kind, but don't delete it.